# related to our all morning activities

Tags: phrases

What we should say for all the morning activities that everyone do daily, like is there any single phrase for that?

like we generally wake up in the morning and then go washroom and do brush and take bath so all these morning activities are there so is there any single phrase for that to say in English

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: like we generally wake up in the morning and then go washroom and do brush and take bath so all these morning activities are there so is there any single phrase for that to say in english

Comment: 'Matutinal activities' is possible, but not many people use it. Why not use the one you already have, 'morning activities'?

Comment: Yes, it would be fine to use "morning activities" but some people maybe don't understand what does "morning activities" mean and thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this word (from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/routine))

> **routine**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** A sequence of actions regularly followed.
> *Each day, they followed a strict routine of work, ritual baths, and prayer.*

So for example you could say

> My morning **routine** on rising is to go to the washroom, brush my teeth and take a bath.

Comment: oh, that's sounds great. thank you